# How do I migrate data (i.e. specific model field values) from a Mezzanine Displayable model to a new custom Mezzanine Page model?

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I'm upgrading a legacy Django/Mezzanine project and need to translate an old `Displayable` model (`Job`) into a `Page` model (`JobPage`).

The old `Job` model looks like this:

```
class Job(Displayable):
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    job_type = models.IntegerField(choices=job_values.TYPES)
    location = models.IntegerField(choices=job_values.LOCATION)
    job_group = models.IntegerField(choices=job_values.GROUPS)

    job_description = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    job_qualifications = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)

    contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    contact_attach = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    contact_email = models.EmailField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.job_title

    @property
    def job_id_on_page(self):
        return slugify(self.job_title)

    def get_page_slug(self):
        return "/%s#%s" % (job_values.URLS[self.job_group],     self.job_id_on_page)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return self.get_page_slug()

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.title = self.job_title
        self.slug = "job-listing/%s" % slugify(self.job_title)
```

I created the `Job Page` model like so:

```
class JobPage(Page):
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    job_type = models.IntegerField(choices=job_values.TYPES)
    location = models.IntegerField(choices=job_values.LOCATION)
    job_group = models.IntegerField(choices=job_values.GROUPS)

    job_description = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    job_qualifications = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)

    contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    contact_attach = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    contact_email = models.EmailField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.title = self.job_title
        self.slug = "job-listing/%s" % slugify(self.job_title)

        super(JobPage, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.job_title
```

and ran:

```
python manage.py makemigratons
python manage.py migrate
```

My strategy for transferring the data was to do a Django data migration (seeing as I'm using Mezzanine 4+ and Django 1.8 and fixtures are being deprecated):

```
python manage.py makemigrations --empty jobapp
```

I go into `jobapp/migrations`, open the empty migration, and type the following:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations

from mezzanine.utils.urls import slugify

def dump_into_jobpage(apps, schema_editor):
    Job = apps.get_model('jobapp','Job')
    JobPage = apps.get_model('jobapp','JobPage')

    fields = ['job_title', 'job_type', 'location', 'job_group',
              'job_description', 'job_qualifications', 'contact_name',
              'contact_attach', 'contact_email']
    site_id = JobPage._meta.get_field('site_id')
    data_dict = {"site_id":1}

    for j in Job.objects.all():
        for field in fields:
            try:
                value = getattr(j, field)
                data_dict[field] = value
            except:
                pass

        data_dict['title'] = data_dict['job_title']
        data_dict['slug'] = 'job-listing/%s' %     slugify(data_dict['job_title'])

        JobPage(**data_dict).save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
        ('jobapp', '0028_jobpage'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(dump_into_jobpage)
    ]
```

I then run:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

and also go into:

```
python manage.py shell
```

to check the all the data migrated correctly, including the native `Page` `slug` field (which causes problems later). I print all `slug` fields for the `Job Page` model successfully.

Problem starts when I `runserver`, go to the admin page, and try to click on 'Pages' so I can see if everything ran smoothly. Of course it didn't run smoothly. I get the following error:

```
Error during template rendering

**In template /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/newcorpsite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/pages/templates/admin/pages/page/change_list.html, error at line 40**
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
30                  <option value="{{ model.add_url }}">{{ model.meta_verbose_name|capfirst }}</option>
31                  {% endif %}
32              {% endfor %}
33          </select> 
34      </div>
35      {% endif %}
36  
37      {% if cl.result_count == 0 %}
38      <p class="paginator">0 {{ cl.opts.verbose_name_plural }}</p>
39      {% else %}
40  
          **<div id="tree">
             {% page_menu "pages/menus/admin.html" %}
          </div>**

41      {% endif %}
42  
43  </div>
44  {% endblock %}
```

Which trace back to:

```
self.html_id = self.slug.replace("/","-")
```

So bascially there's no `slug` field for one or more of the `JobPage`s EVEN THOUGH I JUST SAW THE SLUG ATTRIBUTE IN THE PYTHON SHELL.

I'm going a bit crazy with this one. Anyone know why these field values wouldn't stick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I posted above was created after many failed iterations of trying to figure out how to do this. During those failed iterations, I added the `JobPage` model to the database and then deleted it again several times as I experienced different errors and experimented with different fields and field types. Apparently, when you drop a page model, its objects don't disappear from the `<your_app>.pages_page` database (`pages_page` is the Mezzanine `Page` model database). It instead leaves behind the old entries. If you then delete one of those objects directly like so:

```
Page.objects.get(field=value).delete()
```

or delete/don't fill out a field, the object doesn't actually disappear, but instead a null/None database entry is left behind. The `Page` object does, however, retain its `id` field. I don't know if I have strange settings somewhere that caused this, if it's a Mezzanine thing, or if it's a Django thing, but that's what went down. I was getting the `NoneType` error because Mezzanine saw an entry for a `Page` in the `pages_page` database and tried to create an item for it in the Admin menu. Great, except all the entries for that page were `None`. I couldn't delete the `None` objects in python shell because I'd get an error `Cannot use None as a query value`, but I could print the individual `id`'s, write them down, and manually delete the `Page` objects in the `mysql` shell using their `id`'s.

At that point, I was able to use all the code above to create the new `JobPage`'s successfully.

Another caveat, I had to add this migration to the `JobPage` models since creating them via Django data migrations didn't populate the `content_model` field:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations

def update_jobpage(apps, schema_editor):
    JobPage = apps.get_model('jobapp','JobPage')
    JobPage.objects.all().update(content_model='jobpage')

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('jobapp', '0029_auto_20150911_1624'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(update_jobpage)
    ]
```

Without the `content_model` field, Mezzanine can't use its built in `get_content_model()` function to figure out what custom content type (in this case, `JobPage`, which translates to `jobpage`) the `Page` it's trying to put on the Admin menu is based off of. So it throws an error and blocks you from using the page.

Did I miss something here? Why didn't the old `JobPage` entries go away when I deleted the model? Why did deleting them directly in Python leave a `NoneType` object behind so I had to manually delete them in MySQL?